# Get mean, mode, median and number of incidents from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
        SD_Unlimited    SD        ST        ST_Unlimited
0       0.016667    14.666667   14.666667   14.666667
1       2.466667    2.466667    4.950000    4.950000
2       1.725000    267.825000  1.366667    1.716667
3       5.016667    18.650000   18.650000   5.016667
4       0.005556    10.033333   4.250000    4.238889
```

and I want to produce such a result

```
        SD_Unlimited    SD        ST        ST_Unlimited
mean         1          0         0.01    14.6  
mode        2.4         2.4       4.95    4.9
median      1.7         267.82    1.36    1.71 
count       50          18        50      100
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work.

Answer (score 1):

use
`df.describe()` to get all info

where df represents your dataframe name

Comment: df represents your data frame name

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for adding info - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.mean()  # Calculate Mean

df.median()  # Calculate Median

df.mode()  # Calculate Mode

df.count()  # Calculate count
```

Comment: Thanks but, I know how to produce them, I want to have them on a table and for all columns. somehow automaticaly